# How to access class instance in event hanlder (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code:

```
function Customer(name){
   this._name=name;
};

Customer.prototype.init=function(){
   $('#SetCreditLevel').click(function(){
      //best way to access this._name ?
      //this now points to DOM element

   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?
You could override the value of `this` by setting your own context, but it is very useful to be able to access the DOM object as `this` in jQuery, and a fundamental part of how jQuery works. If you were to change that, I'd say you're not hardly using jQuery at all. So instead, i'm passing context as a parameter here...

```
function Customer(name){
   this._name=name;
};

Customer.prototype.init=function(){
   $('#SetCreditLevel').click((function(context){
       return function() {
           alert(context._name);
           alert(this);
       }
   })(this));
}
```

Comment: it works, but I don't fully understand how. I see a self executing anonymous function which is passed the context, - this part I understand. The body of this function is a mystery to me, though. Why is function being returned? How does it work?

Comment: it's the beauty of javascript *scopes*. jQuery's `click` expects a function. so you execute some code that returns a function, which is then used as the `click` input param. the code that's being executed accepts a `context` parameter, and since it does, that becomes part of the *scope* of the inner function, so that it can be accessed there, with whatever value was originally passed to the parent function.

Comment: That's very elegant, real life usage of closures